# How to set sensitivity header in eml file for Outlook?

Tags: javascript, outlook, mime-types, eml

I'm trying to write an email via a dynamically created eml file with JavaScript.

I've modified this code to my needs from another SO answer but I'm not sure why `Sensitivity` and `Priority` headers are not working when I open the file with Outlook.
In Outlook I see differently named sensitivity levels compared to rfc2156 (company set or Outlook?): "public", "internal", "confidential", and "strictly confidential". Not sure if that's important.

I've tried all possible combinations, with or without double quotes, etc but so far nothing seems to set either headers. I can see them If I read the eml in text editor but when I open the file in Outlook I just see the default settings being applied.

I'm using Outlook version 2102.

```
const emailBody = "<html><body><b>hello</b> world</body></html>";

let emlHeader = "data:message/rfc822 eml;charset=utf-8,";
emlHeader += `From: guy1@mail.io\n`;
emlHeader += `Subject: Sensitive message\n`;
emlHeader += `To: guy2@mail.io\n`;
emlHeader += `Bcc: guy2@mail.io\n`;
emlHeader += `Date: Sun, 10 Jul 2022 03:54:14 +0000\n`;
emlHeader += "Priority: Urgent\n";
emlHeader += "Sensitivity: Private\n";
emlHeader += "X-Unsent: 1\n";

const emlString = `${emlHeader}\n\n${emailBody}`;

const emlContent = encodeURI(emlString); //encode spaces etc like an url
const a = document.createElement("a"); //make a link in document
a.href = emlContent;
a.id = "fileLink";
a.download = "filename.eml";
a.style = "display:none;"; // hidden link
document.body.appendChild(a);
document.getElementById("fileLink").click(); //click the link
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `PR_IMPORTANCE` (possible values are `IMPORTANCE_HIGH`, `IMPORTANCE_NORMAL`, `IMPORTANCE_LOW`), you need `X-Priority` headers with values of `1`, `2`, and `3` correspondingly. You can also set `X-MSMail-Priority` header (Outlook specific) to `High`, `Normal`, `Low`.

For `PR_SENSITIVITY` (possible values in MAPI are `SENSITIVITY_PERSONAL`, `SENSITIVITY_PRIVATE`, `SENSITIVITY_COMPANY_CONFIDENTIAL`), you need to set `Sensitivity` header to `Personal`, `Private`, `Company-Confidential` correspondingly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm half way there... `Importance: high`

Comment: But `Sensitivity` seems to be not working. It does give me an info that "Please treat this as Confidential" below the recipient but the mail body is still marked as `Classified: Company_name – [Internal]` (which is equal to "Personal" i assume)

I've checked the headers of a mail which I've manually set "Strictly Confidential" in Outlook but there is no Sensitivity header (nothing seems to indicate the sensitivity) after receiving it, yet at the end of the email body it shows:
`Classified: Company_name – [Strictly Confidential]`

Any idea how do they achieve that?

Comment: I'm reading about "msip_labels" which is apparently what I'm looking for.
I'll raise another question because I don't know if I can and how to set this header properly in the eml file and will that going to have the desired effect...